# searching an arraylist

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, arraylist

I have a arraylist in my web application project in asp.net/C#/VS2008 and **I'm using .net 3.5**

I'm adding contents to the arraylist using a class which is defined as follows:

```
using System.Web;

class ShoppingCartDataStore
{
    private string componentName;
    private string componentPrice;
    private string componentFileSize;
    private string componentDescription;

    public ShoppingCartDataStore(string componentName, string componentPrice, string componentFileSize, string componentDescription){
        this.componentName = componentName;
        this.componentPrice = componentPrice;
        this.componentFileSize = componentFileSize;
        this.componentDescription = componentDescription;
    }

    public string ComponentName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.componentName;
        }
    }

    public string ComponentPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.componentPrice;
        }
    }

    public string ComponentFileSize
    {
        get
        {
            return this.componentFileSize;
        }
    }

    public string ComponentDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return this.componentDescription;
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm adding contents to the arraylist by following code:

```
ArrayList selectedRowItems = new ArrayList();
selectedRowItems.Add(new ShoppingCartDataStore(componentName, componentPrice, fileSize, componentDescription));
```

Suppose I want to search this arraylist after adding few values in this manner with componentName as the key. I tried the following code but I'm just not able to find a way to do this:

```
ArrayList temporarySelectedItemsList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList presentValue = new ArrayList();
string key = componentName; //some specific component name
temporarySelectedItemsList = selectedRowItems;
for (int i = 0; i < temporarySelectedItemsList.Count; i++)
{
    presentValue = (ArrayList)temporarySelectedItemsList[i];
}
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If you're using .NET 2.0 or above, then you shouldn't be using `ArrayList`.

Comment: Unless you are targetting .net pre v2, then you should almost certainly use a generic list

Comment: @John can u explain why shouldn't i be using arraylist if i'm using .net 2.0 or above ? what's wrong with that ? If not arraylist then what should i be using in its place ?

Comment: What you want to use is List<ShoppingCartDataStore>. There's several advantages, including enforcing that you only add the correct type, not having to cast data when you use it (because it knows the type of what is in it already), and being able to use some helpful operators like List.Sort and List.Contains.

Comment: @user: I also strongly recommend that you not repeat your tags in the title. Keep the tags in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = selectedRowItems.OfType<ShoppingCartDataStore>().Where(x=>x.ComponentName == "foo")
```

of course you could get rid of the OfType if you were using a generic list rather than a arraylist

EDIT: So, I have no idea why you would NOT use LINQ or generics if you are in 3.5. But if you must:

```
ArrayList results = new ArrayList();


foreach (ShoppingCartDataStore store in selectedRowItems)
{
    if(store.ComponentName == "foo"){
        results.Add(store);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not using linq in my project can u explain in normal c# code ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sick and this is untested, but I think it'll work. :)

```
List<ShoppingCartDataStore> aList = new List<ShoppingCartDataStore>();
// add your data here

string key = componentName; //some specific component name
// Now search
foreach (ShoppingCartDataStore i in aList)
{
    if (i.ComponentName == key)
    {
        // Found, do something
    }
}
```